# .bashrc code to execute 1 time a day upon first login

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to make a specific piece of code in my .bashrc file execute only on the first log-in of a specific day of the week? I already know that using the command substitution 
"$(date +%u)" will give me a number from 1-7 that corresponds to each day of the week (1 being Monday). However, i do not want this code to execute all day for every subsequent log-in. Any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A [user anacron](http://osmanov-dev-notes.blogspot.nl/2010/12/anacron-for-user.html) seems to do what you want, and versatile enough to do lots more. Of course, if you need only this little bit, locking, checking & writing a date to some file is a way more lightweight approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to write anything to disk.

I would extract the day out of the commands:
lastlog -u $USER 
and 
date

Then do the appropriate matches/comparisons.

The logic would be something like:

```
    get day from date
    if day from date is the magic day, then
      get day from from lastlog -u $USER
      if day does not match today's day then
        run your command
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use what is called 'semaphore file', something like this:

```
if [[ ! -e /tmp/$(date +%u).sem ]]
then
    touch /tmp/$(date +%u).sem
    # Do your one-time stuff
fi
```

However, which approach you choose, I would recommend you to use a full date (date +"%Y%m%d") to avoid potential bug if the user login on Monday, and his next login is in the next Monday.

Answer (score 0):

```
date +%u |                  ## Generate timestamp (could be a better date-spec)
   tee timestamp.tmp |      ## Save a copy for later usage
   cmp - timestamp ||       ## Fail if date-spec changed
   {  
      ## In that case, update timestamp
      mv timestamp.tmp timestamp && 

      ## And only if that succeeds, run your code
      echo "Once a day" ;
    }
```

I prefer to touch the timestamp BEFORE running de command, because it is usually safer not to run anything at all than running it repeatedly. (The partition could have been remounted read-only, the disk might be full, permissions could have been changed...)